# get data from JSON with php

Tags: php, json, get

I am trying to get data from a JSON page:
http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json

I am getting errors.

How do I get the "data" array from the JSON?

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json');
$result   = json_decode($result);
$result   = utf8_encode($result); 
print_r($result);
```

Comment: The argument to `utf8_encode()` should be a string. `json_encode()` returns an object.

Comment: so what i need to do? can you please give me example or something?

Comment: Just get rid of `utf8_encode`. There's no reason to use it here anyway.

Comment: i use utf8_encode bcz the title on hebrew, and the array will be in hebrew when that will update

Comment: You said you just want the data array, so why does the title matter?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Barmar bcz in the array, the text in hebrew... so i need that in utf-8.

Comment: @Barmar and i need the title for something more :)

Comment: `utf8_encode` cannot help you with Hebrew text by definition to begin with. Please read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$result = file_get_contents ("http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json");

```
 $result = iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $result);
 $json = json_decode($result);
 echo $json->id;
 echo $json->title;
```

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode` returns an object (or an associative array if you give the second argument `true`). To get the `data` array, you need to use a property accessor:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json');
$result = json_decode($homepage);
$data = $result->data;
print_r($data);
```

If you need to encode the `$data` array in UTF8, use:

```
$data = array_map('utf8_encode', $result->data);
```

To get the title, use:

```
$title = utf8_encode($data->title);
```

Comment: I try that, for check i change "data" to "title" and change print_r to print bcz "title" is string, didn`t show anything...

Comment: You can't use `array_map` on a string, just encode the string directly.

Comment: the title didn`t work, i do var_dump to check, and that print " string(0) "" "

Comment: The problem seems to be that the website is not returning valid JSON. It looks like it's actually JSON that has been encoded as multibyte characters. I tried calling `utf8_decode()` before calling `json_decode()`, but that didn't help.

Comment: The result of `json_decode` should already be UTF-8, no need for `utf8_encode` here at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json');
$result = json_decode($result);
print_r($result->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are first `json_decode($result);` but `$result` has not been declared before this line.

Secondly, the logically order of your code is totally wrong:

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json');
$result = utf8_encode($result); // encode the data before decoding json

$result = json_decode($result, true); // specify true to get an associated array

print_r($result);
```

Comment: nope, didn`t show anything, and i try and change "print_r" to "var_dump" and that show "NULL"

Comment: `file_get_contents` returns JSON, there's no need to call `json_encode`.

Comment: @wyd3x `utf8_encode()` fails because the data fetched is not ISO-8859-1. If you know the encoding of the original data, you can use `iconv()` to convert it to utf8.

Comment: @Barmar that's not true, `file_get_contents` return string.

Comment: JSON _is_ a string. That website returns a string containing JSON (except see the comment I just added below my answer -- it's not properly formatted JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Test.json:

```
{
    "John":{
        "name":"Json"
    },
    "James":{   
        "status":"Active",
        "age":56,
        "count":10,
        "progress":0.0029857,
        "bad":0
    }
}
```

json.php:

```
$result= file_get_contents("test.json");
$get_data = json_decode($result, true);

echo $get_data['John']['name'].'<br/>';
echo $get_data['James']['age'];
```