# How to get JSON data with PHP

Tags: php, json, dictionary

I am new with PHP and I am just trying to get one value from a JSON dictionary. This seems really simple (at least to me) but I am having trouble with it. I looked at the PHP documentation for `JSON_decode` and I also looked at "[Parsing JSON data from a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021266/parsing-json-data-from-a-remote-server)" but that didn't do what I wanted. It returned the dictionary item I wanted as 0 then just spit out the JSON file. Then I looked at "[get data from JSON with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725519/get-data-from-json-with-php)" and that just returns nothing.

**JSON Example**

```
{ 
  "ask": 344.28,
  "bid": 343.89,
  "last": 343.97
}
```

**First Try**

```
$jsoncontent=file_get_contents("https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/USD");`
$priceusd=json_decode($json-content);

$lastusd=$priceusd['last'];

echo "Decoded JSON:\n";
echo "$priceusd\n";
echo "Raw JSON:\n";
echo "$jsoncontent\n";
```

**Second Try**

```
$result=file_get_contents("https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/USD");
 $result = iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $result);
 $json = json_decode($result);

 echo $json->last;
```

All I want is the value of one of the dictionary items in JSON at a URL.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide an example structure of the JSON you are working with?

Comment: `{
  "ask": 344.28,
  "bid": 343.89,
  "last": 343.97,
}` I want to echo the last value.

Comment: where are your trials?

Comment: @Jake you don't need an `iconv()` in there, just straight up decode it. check out barmar's answer below

Comment: This line `$priceusd=json_decode($json-content);` must be like: `$priceusd=json_decode($jsoncontent);` 
Variable name doesnt have "-" in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `$data` contains what was returned from the server, you do:

```
$object = json_decode($data);
$last = $object->last;
```

or:

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
$last = $array['last'];
```

When you leave out the second argument to `json_decode`, it returns an object, and you access the part you want as an object property. If you give the second argument `true`, it returns an associative array, and you access the element using array notation.